# Sequelize - get proper path while validating associations of a model

Tags: node.js, postgresql, validation, orm, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize as an ORM for my project. I have this structure:

```
const Event = sequelize.define('event', {
    // fields defined
});

const Question = sequelize.define('question', {
    description: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: '',
        validate: {
            notEmpty: { msg: 'Description should be set.' }
       },
    },
    // other fields defined
});

Event.hasMany(Question);
Question.belongsTo(Event);
```

Then I create an instance of the Event model, with associate, like that:

```
const body = {
    questions: [
        { description: '' } // is obviously invalid
    ],
    // some other fields
}

const newEvent = await Event.create(body, {
    include: [ Question ]
});
```

If I have validation errors for the Event instance itself, it returns `SequelizeValidationError` where I can see the `path` attribute for each `ValidationErrorItem`. However, when I have the validation error on a child model, the `path` attribute for this validation error is unclear:

```
{
    "message": "Description should be set.",
    "type": "Validation error",
    "path": "description",
    "value": "",
    "origin": "FUNCTION",
    "instance": {
        "required": true,
        "id": null,
        "description": "",
        "event_id": 60,
        "updated_at": "2018-06-11T12:25:04.666Z",
        "created_at": "2018-06-11T12:25:04.666Z"
    },
    "validatorKey": "notEmpty",
    "validatorName": "notEmpty",
    "validatorArgs": [
        {
            "msg": "Description should be set."
        }
    ],
    "__raw": {
        "validatorName": "notEmpty",
        "validatorArgs": [
            {
                "msg": "Description should be set."
            }
        ]
    }
```

The problem is, it's unclear what caused this error and which child is invalid. When I've used Mongoose as an ORM, if I'd do the same, the `path` attribute would be equal to something like `questions.0.description`, and that is way more clear, that way you can see which child is invalid.

So, my question is: is there a way to set up the `path` attribute while validating the child models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's not presented yet, I've filed an issue on Sequelize repo, here it is: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/9524